# Using Selenium Grid and Java, Firefox and Chrome run smoothly on Mac, but Safari breaks at bottom of the page - won't scroll

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, selenium-grid

I've been trying to find a solution to this specific problem online all day. Let me provide as much information as I can.

I am using selenium grid 3, with windows server as the hub and my macbook as the node
Everything works as it should on the mac in chrome and firefox.
I took care of the setup in safari as expected (developer, allow automations, and then ran that safaridriver command on /usr/local/bin safaridriver (whatever that was))
When I set the browser to safari, it opens up as it should. The hub and node are properly configured to communicate.

My macbook is connected by HDMI to an HP 24 inch monitor.
When the the grid opens safari in the HP monitor, after it applies the driver.manage().window().maximize(), it shows 8 elements on the screen. Automation fails after that 8th element - It will not scroll past it at all.

When the grid opens safari in the macbook screen ("built-in retina display"), , after it applies the driver.manage().window().maximize(), it shows 4 elements on the screen. It scrolls once and shows the next 7 elements. But once it gets to that 7th element, automation fails. The error I get is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '[redacted]', ip: '[redacted]', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: '[redacted]', ip: '[redacted]', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_271'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{safari:diagnose=false, strictFileInteractability=false, platform=ANY, safari:automaticProfiling=false, webdriver.remote.sessionid=9834B185-E31A-4433-8F7F-0E035C280406, safari:platformBuildVersion=19F101, webkit:WebRTC={DisableICECandidateFiltering=false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture=false}, browserVersion=13.1.1, safari:useSimulator=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, safari:platformVersion=10.15.5, browserName=Safari, safari:automaticInspection=false, platformName=macOS, setWindowRect=true}]
Session ID: 9834B185-E31A-4433-8F7F-0E035C280406
```

Is there anything in there that tells anyone what the issue is? I can't figure it out. I've tried adding scrolls, but I don't think I should have to for just this one browser, should I? There must be some configuration I could adjust? I tried removing the HDMI and using just the macbook itself, nothing I have tried works.

If anyone knows anything that could help, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Though your [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) version is **3.141.59** but your *JDK* version **1.8.0_71** is too old and ancient.

```
System info: host: '[redacted]', ip: '[redacted]', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I downloaded and installed that version at the top of the lin you provided. Same error, but now it says :  os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '15.0.1'

Comment: Also on one of your other solutions, my versions of standalone are different. But when I change them to the same version (3.141.59) I get this other error about not one of the last 1000 terminated sessions. Weird, because I don't get that error with different versions (hub has 3.0.1)